# Where can you change the #type of a checkbox?

Tags: forms

I have content type with a taxonomy attached to it (since it is Drupal 8, it ends up being an Entity Reference field).  The form is configured to render out this field input as checkboxes.

I have run into a situation where I need to change some of the checkboxes into plain text when the form is rendered (node create, note edit etc).  I tried to push a `#process` function onto the field,

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_job_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_foo']['widget']['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_foo';
}

function MYMODULE_foo(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
  // do stuff
}
```

but when I inspect the `$element` with XDebug, the `#options` haven't been processed yet.

So, where in the form / render pipeline can this be changed?

Comment: `I need to change some of the check boxes into plain text` You didn't say explicitly when? when the form is viewed? submitted? or...??? Could affect the answer.

Comment: You could just unset them and add a new form key with `#markup`.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks. I would normally do that, but the question is a huge simplification of my actual problem. Essentially I need the top level terms available for reference in the form in the order that they are on the taxonomy page (like headings), but only for certain roles.  Other roles always get the checkboxes. Lots of fine-grained access control on this site; its more web-app than pure CMS.

Comment: Can't you solve that using an if statement... `if ($current_logged_in_user_role = 'some_role') { unset($form['some-checkbox']); }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside preprocess you can add code to the rendering of form elements in `#pre_render`, `#theme`, `#theme_wrappers` and `#post_render`. Part of the rendering pipeline of checkboxes is for example `CompositeFormElementTrait::preRenderCompositeFormElement`:

```
  public static function preRenderCompositeFormElement($element) {
    // Set the element's title attribute to show #title as a tooltip, if needed.
    if (isset($element['#title']) && $element['#title_display'] == 'attribute') {
      $element['#attributes']['title'] = $element['#title'];
      if (!empty($element['#required'])) {
        // Append an indication that this field is required.
        $element['#attributes']['title'] .= ' (' . t('Required') . ')';
      }
    }

    if (isset($element['#title']) || isset($element['#description'])) {
      // @see #type 'fieldgroup'
      $element['#attributes']['id'] = $element['#id'] . '--wrapper';
      $element['#theme_wrappers'][] = 'fieldset';
      $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'fieldgroup';
      $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-composite';
    }
    return $element;
```